# How to finish parent activity from child activity without finishing/stopping child activity?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am beginner to android. Can anyone help me with an example of this?

So far I have searched for it but didn't find useful stuff. Only found that closing the parent activity also need to close child activity with setResult() method.

What exactly I am looking for is that my parent activity should be closed from child activity without finishing the child activity.

Answer (score 1):

From the child activity, try using the getParent() method which returns the parent activity, and finish() it !

Comment: the getParent() call only works for embedded activies, e.g. Activitygroup (now deprecated). For regular activities getParent() will always return null.

Answer (score 1):

The activity back stack works like a stack, i.e. you can pop and push activities onto it. You can not remove an activity from the stack without first removing an activity above it on the stack. It is therefore probably impossible for a child to finish its parent´s activity without first finishing itself.

There are several methods you can use to reorder or even clear the activity back stack through the use of  [launchmodes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) and [Intent flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create a static variable of Context like 
**static Context cntxofParent;** in ParentActivity

Then initialize that reference in Parent Activiy like

**cntxofParent=ParentActivityName.this;**

When you are in child activity then collect that Context and cast it into Activity as below,

**Activity parentActivity;**

**parentActivity=(Activity)cntxofParent;**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about [Task and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

For a start, activities in android are put on a stack called an, if my memory serves me right, Activity Stack. When you start an activity you can add an intent flag that will affect the stack, like

addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

I think I've done what you are trying to do before (I'm not sure what flag I used though, it was a long time ago :p). But just read about activity task to know what intent flag is suited of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!
Nice tutorial for understanding task and back stack. but didn't find any matching intent flag for finishing parent activity from the child activity as per my requirement. here, this one declaring in parent activity itself.

Answer (score -1):

Activity A - > Activity B , 
remove Activity A ,

if this is what you are looking for

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but i want to finish parent activity from child activity.

Comment: @sunny Read the question properly before answering.